# How do I memo a simple function in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, memoization

What would be the simplest way to memoize the `FooProvider.load(): FooProvider` call here, i.e. do it only once.

So the `load` call supplies a "loaded" instance of `FooProvider`. In my special case it parses an XML file.

I want to built a kind of "library" singleton, which says: "Give me an execution context once to load a file and then I will cache it forever". I just don't want to use a specific ExecutionContext in the library, but I want the caching to happen in the library as soon as it gets one.

I have seen some examples with Scalaz's `Memo` which supplies HashMaps for recursive functions like prime and fibonacci, but what would you use in a simple use case like this (maybe without any library)?

```
  val provider: ExecutionContext => Future[FooProvider] = {
    def load(ec: ExecutionContext) = FooProvider.load(ec)
    executionContext => load(executionContext)
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you want to memonize here.

Comment: Corrected my question. FooProvider.load(ec: ExecutionContext) is the costly call that should be memoized. See also my current solution below. Is there a better / simpler / shorter way?

Comment: Will you be calling this function with different ECs? or just with one in the main? if with many, you want to cache one instance per EC or one for all? - Finally, do you really need to make the caching in this point? Maybe you can do the caching inside `FooProvider.load` or where you call this function. **Futures** are eager and demonized so if you do this: `val fooProvider = provider(ec)` and you keep reusing that `fooProvider` everywhere, then the value will be only computed once.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your solution works, I did this a lot of times in the past.

But here I want to built a kind of "library" singleton, which says: "Give me an execution context once to load a file and then I will cache it forever". I just don't want to use a specific ExecutionContext in the library, but I want the caching to happen in the library as soon as it gets one.

I corrected my own answer now, the former didn't work for obvious reasons.

The code now does exactly what I specified above, just wondering if there are other solutions to it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this now:

```
val provider: ExecutionContext => Future[FooProvider] = {
    val providerRefMemoized = mutable.Map[Unit, Future[FooProvider]]()

    (executionContext) =>
      providerRefMemoized.getOrElseUpdate((), FooProvider.load(executionContext))
  }
```